# JS numbers counter only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery

so my counter works just the first time.
by clicking in the button again i need to continue counting, but the function don't works after run first time, anyone know how to do it?

My jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wtkd/xpqg0fa9/

My js if you don't want to see in jsFiddle:

```
window.Fighters = (function() {
  var padNum;

  function Fighters(options) {
    var random;
    this.greenFighter = $('.green-fighter');
    this.blueFighter = $('.blue-fighter');
    this.team = $('.green-team, .blue-team');
    this.thumb = $('.thumb');
    random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 301232);
    $('.punch1').on('click', (function(_this) {
      return function(e) {
        return _this.countUp(random, '.right-counter span', 2222);
      };
    })(this));
    $('.punch2').on('click', (function(_this) {
      return function(e) {
        return _this.countUp(random, '.left-counter span', 2222);
      };
    })(this));
  }

  padNum = function(number) {
    if (number < 10) {
      return '0' + number;
    }
    return number;
  };

  Fighters.prototype.countUp = function(points, selector, duration) {
    $({
      countNumber: $(selector).text()
    }).animate({
      countNumber: points
    }, {
      duration: duration,
      easing: 'linear',
      step: function() {
        $(selector).text(padNum(parseInt(this.countNumber)));
      },
      complete: function() {
        $(selector).text(points);
      }
    });
  };

  return Fighters;

})();
new window.Fighters();
```

Comment: Questions that ask "why isn't this code working?" should be revised to fit the guidelines of SO http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (First category)

Comment: I would say this fits the guidelines "must include the desired behavior" check, "a specific problem or error" check, "and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click function is running each time but with the same reference to random. Random is evaluated once on the first execute of your script this is then used within your closure not re-evaluated. (literally tons of articles relating to closures to that you can read up on if you need to - here is one - http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)

Bring the random inside your closure to ensure it evaluated on each click like so:

```
$('.punch1').on('click', (function(_this) {
      return function(e) {
          random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 301232);
        return _this.countUp(random, '.right-counter span', 2222);
      };
    })(this));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6gwyv0x/1/

or make random a function which returns it's value

```
random = function(){return Math.ceil(Math.random() * 301232);};
$('.punch1').on('click', (function(_this) {
  return function(e) {

    return _this.countUp(random(), '.right-counter span', 2222);
  };
})(this));
```

random still refers to the one outside the closure but because it is a function it will be run on each click returning a new number
http://jsfiddle.net/y6gwyv0x/3/

Comment: i'm really grateful to you by this too complete answer!!!!